# NSNotification multiple observers, only one gets called

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I have 2 observers registered. One of them is in appDelegate and the other is in myViewController. When I am in myViewController, I just expect to get two notifications, one from appDelegate which executes some method globally, the other one from myViewController which executes some other method. But, only the one in appDelegate gets called. If I remove the observer in appDelegate, the observer in myViewController gets called. Actually, I can just use the observer method in appDelegate and find out the current view controller and execute the code of the method in myViewController. But, I just don't wanna mess appDelegate. The same code for both of them but I remove the observer in myViewController when viewWillDisappear() method gets called. Any ideas? Thanks.

**appDelegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self   
                                             selector:@selector(someMethod:)
                                                 name:@"someName"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"someName"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:someUserInfo];
}

- (void)someMethod:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // gets called
}
```

**myViewController**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(someMethod:)
                                                 name:@"someName"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:@"someName"
                                                  object:nil];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)someMethod:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // not called
}
```

Comment: post the code u used for posting notification

Comment: also, where are you registering/removing your observers ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have edited the post. Have a look.

Comment: Don't put additional code in your app delegate. That's not what it's for!!!

Comment: Actually, posting happens from push notification which means the both observers are already registered. Because I run the app, the observer in appDelegate gets registered, then go to myViewController, viewWillAppear() method gets called and the observer in it gets registered. Then, push notification comes and I post the notification which triggers the method in appDelegate only. If I remove the observer in appDelegate and re-run the app and go to myViewController, the observer in it gets called.

Comment: I have updated the code to make it more clear. I am sorry for not doing it earlier and wasted your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code below you're posting before observing

```
 (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"someName"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:someUserInfo];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self   
                                             selector:@selector(someMethod:)
                                                 name:@"someName"
                                               object:nil];
}
```

***  Original ***
Plenty of possible issues here:

one the notification Name could be spelt wrong = @"someName" - If this is going to be observe red from other classes, think about creating an

in  a .h (that both classes import)
include

```
extern NSString * const XXXSomeNameForSomeNotification;
```

in the corresponding .m

```
NSString * const XXXSomeNameForSomeNotification = @"someName";
```

That's one way to ensure they're all observing/posting the right notification

If that's not your issue then try adding observing the notification from the viewDidLoad or another method that's called prior to viewDidAppear  as it could be that it's not observing you notification when it's actually posted. Add break points to observe this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I am doing like that. I just provided a pseudo code which is exactly the same. I just didn't want to be too verbose :).

Comment: You are right. But, actually I added an observer before posting. The code is wrong. Sorry, my mistake. I have updated it.

Comment: Try changing the name of your notification. Have you set a break points to see what order things are triggered when you run the app, also are 100% it's not working i.e. what's the indicator.

Comment: You were right. I was removing the observer before posting. Because when I get a push notification, the app presents a another view controller and the myViewController's viewWillDisappear() gets called and removes the observer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think as per you posted code the reason is

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:@"someName"
                                              object:nil];

[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

}
```

The method above will remove the notification observing if the current view is not on screen.

Also you may want to move the

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:@"someName"
                                              object:nil];
```

to

```
- (void) dealloc
{
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:@"someName"
                                                  object:nil];
}
```

that way you only stop observing the notification when you remove the view controller form memory. You may want to check in the method that's called if you're on screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why? I am just removing the observer in myViewController, not from appDelegate.

Comment: Before your modification you was posting notification before adding it so for sure it won't call for appdelegate. An for your comment notification will surely fire for appdelegate. But, for which ever class it was removed not for those. Because whenever you viewcontroller will dissapear from screen it will call that disappear method.

Comment: Please, have a look at my last comment. Thanks

Comment: For your viewcontroller where are you calling your notification? For appdelegate you are doing that, but not for viewcontroller.

Comment: @Sukhrob You can follow this approach what ever iosDevSi has suggested. This will be better one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, Your notification is posted before view is loaded. See adding some logs.

OR try this -

```
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"someName"
                                                            object:nil
                                                          userInfo:someUserInfo];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are right. Please, have a look at the last comment I added.